# query to change database user in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server authentication with login name `sa` (default)

When I execute query

`select session_user`

I get `dbo` as a user. I want to change this, how can I do this using SQL query? Also what is a schema in SQL?

Answer (score 1):

Sql server has 2 different notions

- login: what you use to connect to the server
- User: what you give rights to in a database

When your login is granted database access you are actually creating a database user mapped to the login. The `sa` is the system administrator account and mapped to the dbo (database owner user) on the system databases. When you are logged in with a user with the create database right and create a new database this login will be automatically mapped to the `dbo` user.

If you want to change this afterwards, you need to map the `dbo` user to a new login. Afterwards you can map the `sa` account to another database user.

```
use master
create login xxx with password = 'yyy', check_policy = off
use <yourdatabase>
exec sp_changedbowner 'xxx'
create user 'newuser' from login 'sa'
```

This way the `sa` login will be mapped to the `newuser` database user from now on.

A schema is a securable item which can be used to group database objects. Each database user has a "default schema" assigned.

Answer (score 0):

Schema is a way of categorising the objects in a database. It can be useful if you have several applications share a single database and while there is some common set of data that all application accesses.

DBO is a DataBase Owner. You have created the database and you are a database owner.